# Can I return variables in addition to the gradient using tf.registergradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-gradient

I have a question about the tf.registergradient operation

I am using @tf.registergradient to make custom changes to the tensorflow gradients. Note: I am not modifying only the delta part of the backpopogated gradients. This is working fine. But now I want to save the variables that I am modifying, both before and after the modifications, so that I can analyse them later after I am done training. However I am not sure how to do this.
Here is the code snippet

@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomModGrad")

def noise_delta(unused_op, delta):
    noiz = tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(grad), stddev=sigma_value)
    delta = tf.add(delta,noiz)
    return delta

I want to store the noiz and delta variables so that I can analyze them later. How do I do this? Thank You!

Comment: Have to tried to log `noiz` to summary logger?

Comment: Hi Maxim. Thanks a lot. I got it to work based on your suggestion using TensorBoard. Thanks!